# How to deploy all my contracts from same address (without writing .connect() a bunch of times)?

Tags: wallets, hardhat, addresses, network, mnemonic

I have a mnemonic in my `.env`.

I added it to my `hardhat.config.js` as such:

```
accounts: {
    mnemonic: process.env.MNEMONIC,
    path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
    initialIndex: 0,
    count: 20,
    passphrase: "",
}
```

However, all my contracts are still being deployed by the 1st signer in `getSigners()`.

Questions:

1. How do I deploy all my contracts from the 1st address generated by my mnemonic (without having to write `.connect()` for each ContractFactory)? Essentially, how do I change the default signer?
2. How do I get multiple signers from my one mnemonic?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but i think there is no way to change the default signer, that's why the .connect method was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to change the default deployer.

- Changing the starting index

You can change the default by increasing the `initialIndex` in the accounts section of the configuration file.

```
accounts: {
  mnemonic: process.env.MNEMONIC,
  path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
  initialIndex: 1,           // <---- start with index 1
  count: 20,
  passphrase: "",
}
```

- Configure the signer when getting the contract factory

The `getContractFactory` accepts a signer as second parameter.

```
const [firstAccount, secondAccount, thirdAccount] = await ethers.getSigners();

const Lock = await ethers.getContractFactory("Lock", thirdAccount);
```